# How to search a node through Selenium and Python as per the HTML provided?

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I am using Python and Selenium to search the node, the code is:

```
br.find_element_by_css_selector('dd[_position="3"] a[title="test.docx"]')
```

It is fine to locate in the Sub node under `<div class="text"...`; but I want to locate in the Sub node under `<div class="operate"...` using code:

```
br.find_element_by_css_selector('dd[_position="3"] div[class="button-box-mark"]')
```

It is failed, and I check the subnode under "operate", there is nothing. Can anyone help me with this topic?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried with xpath :- br.find_element_by_xpath_selector('div[class="button-box-mark"]')

Comment: i tried xpah, classname, css, all are failed to locate the sub element under <class="operate" , it is so strange

Comment: Post your HTML inside the question.

Comment: seems selenium can't locate the correct path, if i use code br.find_element_by_xpath('dd[_position="3"]/div[1]/*') i can see the node "operate" and its sub element, do you know why it will ?

Answer (score 0):

As per the snapshot of the *HTML* you have provided to identify the *child node* of the node marked as **Sub Node 2** you can use either of the the following *Locator Strategies*:

- *css-selector*:

  ```
  br.find_element_by_css_selector("dd[_position=3] div.file-name div.operate > div.button-box-mark")
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  br.find_element_by_xpath("//dd[@_position='3']//div[@class='file-name']//div[@class='operate']/div[@class='button-box-mark']")
  ```

Comment: seems selenium can't locate the correct path, if i use code br.find_element_by_xpath('dd[_position="3"]/div[1]/*') i can see the node "operate" and its sub element, do you know why it will ?